# Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, divisibility

I need to determine which of the elements $3+2\sqrt{5}$, $9+4\sqrt{5}$ and $4-\sqrt{5}$ are prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, respectively which are associated.

My ansatz is as follows:

So let $x=3+2\sqrt{5}$ divide $ab$ for $a,b \in R$. Thus, there are $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that
$$ab=(a_1+b_1\sqrt{5})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{5})=(a_1a_2+5b_1b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1\sqrt{5})=(u+v\sqrt{5})(3+2\sqrt{5})=(3u+10v)+(3v+2u)\sqrt{5}.$$
How do I go from here in order to check whether $x|a$ or $x|b$?

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was about irreducible elements, not prime elements, which need not be irreducible in non-UFDs.

Comment: @HermeticallySealedHalibut So the norm doesn't help to check for prime?

Comment: In general, no, at least not as directly as it does with irreducibles. It is still a useful tool though, see lhf's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$3+2\sqrt{5}$ has norm $-11$ and $4-\sqrt{5}$ has norm $11$. Perhaps they are associates. Indeed
$$
\frac{3+2\sqrt{5}}{4-\sqrt{5}} = 2+\sqrt{5}
$$
and $2+\sqrt{5}$ is a unit because it has norm $-1$. In fact, $(2+\sqrt{5})(-2+\sqrt{5})=1$.

$9+4\sqrt{5}$ is a unit because it has norm $1$ and so $(9+4\sqrt{5})(9-4\sqrt{5})=1$.

It remains to decide whether $3+2\sqrt{5}$ is prime. Consider
$$
\frac{\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]}{\langle 3+2\sqrt{5} \rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]}{\langle 3+2\sqrt{5},11 \rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{\langle X^2-5,3+2X,11 \rangle}
\cong
\frac{\mathbb Z_{11}[X]}{\langle X^2-5,3+2X \rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z_{11}[X]}{\langle X^2-5,2(7+X) \rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z_{11}[X]}{\langle X^2-5,X+7 \rangle}
=
\frac{\mathbb Z_{11}[X]}{\langle X+7 \rangle}
\cong
\mathbb Z_{11}
$$
which is a domain. Therefore, $3+2\sqrt{5}$ is prime.

Comment: $(1)$ Why $2(7+X)=X+7$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[X]$ in the last line? and $(2)$ How did you abolished the factor $x^2-5$  in the equality $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[X]/ \left\langle X^2-5,X+7 \right\rangle=\mathbb{Z}_{11}[X]/\left\langle X+7 \right\rangle $. Please explain

Comment: @Why: (1) $2$ is invertible mod $11$, (2) $(X-7)(X+7)=X^2-49=X^2-5 \bmod 11$.

Comment: oh,nice. Thank you very much