# Is $(4+\sqrt{5})$ a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider the integral domain  $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$. Is $(4+\sqrt{5})$ a prime ideal of  $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$?

I know the following elementary facts. We have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right] = \left\{ \frac{m + n \sqrt{5}}{2} : m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ are both even or both odd} \right\}.
\end{equation}

For every $\frac{m + n \sqrt{5}}{2} \in \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$, define its norm as usual:
\begin{equation}
N\left(\frac{m + n \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=\frac{m^2-5n^2}{4}.
\end{equation}
Since $m, n$ are both even or both odd, it is easy to see that the norm is an integer. From this fact it is easily seen that $\frac{m + n \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$ if and only if $m^2 - 5n^2=4$ or $m^2 - 5n^2=-4$. Now since $N(4+\sqrt{5})=11$ we easily get that $4+\sqrt{5}$ is an irreducible element of  $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$. If $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$ were a unique factorization domain, we could conclude that $(4+\sqrt{5})$ a prime ideal of  $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$. But I do not know if $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$ is a unique factorization domain. Does someone know if it is?

Thank you very much in advance for your attention.

Comment: It is a unique factorization domain! This post and the linked posts there may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/golden-number-theory

Comment: You don't need to know whether the ring is a UFD or not. Because the norm is equal to $11$, the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt5)/2]/\langle 4+\sqrt5\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{11}$, which is a field and an integral domain. Therefore....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Dear Jyrki, how could you guess it?! I feel pure wonder! Thanks very very ... much for your incredible insights!

Comment: Thanks, you see that Bart detailed this same idea. How? Experience and practice! And a strong tendency to try and find ways to prove things with as little technology as possible. The last point may be related to having a background in contest math (but also to relative lack of success in research).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $A = \mathbb Z \left[ \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}2\right]$. We can show that $A / (4+\sqrt 5) \cong \mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z$, so that the ideal $(4 + \sqrt 5)$ is maximal.

1. As $N(4 + \sqrt 5) = 11$, it is clear that the elements $0, 1, \ldots, 10$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $4 + \sqrt 5$.
2. Every element of $A$ is congruent to an integer modulo $4 + \sqrt 5$: indeed, if it is of the form $a + b \sqrt 5$ with $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ we can subtract a suitable integer multiple of $4 + \sqrt5$ to land in $\mathbb Z$. If it is of the form $(a+b\sqrt5)/2$ with $a, b$ odd, we can subtract
   $$\frac{1 + \sqrt5}2 \cdot (4 + \sqrt5) = \frac{9 + 5\sqrt5}2$$
   to land in $\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z\sqrt5$.

Consider the ring homomorphism
$$\mathbb Z / (11) \to A / (4+\sqrt5) \,.$$
By the first observation, it is injective. By the second, it is surjective.

Comment: Dear Bart, this is an incredibly beautiful and remarkably elegant solution!!! It is a pure joy to grasp it! Thank you very very ... much for having carefully written down it in detail!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The number field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ has class number one because its Minkowski bound satisfies $B_K<2$ . Hence its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$ is even a PID and hence a UFD.

On the other hand, it is enough to see that $\mathcal{O}_K/(4+\sqrt{5})$ is a field, so that the ideal $(4+\sqrt{5})$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$ is a UFD because it is [norm-Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields).